# Generic SSO solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, azure, single-sign-on

I'm using Windows Azure ACS for SSO implementation. SSO client are web applications ASP.MVC and PHP.

the problem is that Windows Azure currently supports only 3 social providers Microsoft, Yahoo and Google.
What is the best way to add additional providers LinkedIn for example?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I understand this is little old, but have you looked at http://www.socialsts.com/ - this is a bridge between Azure ACS and `LinkedIn`, `Twitter`, `GitHub`, `StackExchange`, `Amazon`, `BitBucket`.

Answer (score 2):

We too were in the same boat :). We have been using ACS for user authentication but could not find a way to extend it to support other social identity providers for the solution we are building. We ended up dumping ACS in favor of [`DotNetOpenAuth`](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) library. It has inbuilt support for 6 ID providers - Windows Live, Google, Facebook, Yahoo, Twitter and LinkedIn and has a lot of extensibility points to add other ID providers. Do take a look at it. Other alternative would be to use [`ThinkTecture Identity Server`](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2). Both of these solutions are open source.

Comment: Thanks, we are currently thinking about hybrid solution ACS with custom STS service that will encapsulate support for missing providers types based on DoNetOpenAuth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can really do it with ACS. As they are OAuth2 implementations they don’t really fit into ACS. Here's the explanation : http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/02/oauth-2-0-and-sign-in-4/

I know that there is an integration attempt with ASP.NET Web Api but not with pure MVC : https://github.com/maartenba/WindowsAzure.Acs.Oauth2

Maybe you can add Web Api to your solution to handle the authentication and authorization ? I know it's not the best solution but can think about something else.